# ¿Cómo escribir un sumatorio?

Tags: r

Necesito escribir la siguiente fórmula en R pero me está costando debido al sumatorio. ¿Podrían ayudarme?

La fórmula es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Un ejemplo de lo que haría la formula es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que yo he intentado hasta ahora es lo siguiente:

```
      Y <- 1
      for (i in 1:length(A)) {
        Y <- Y + A^(i)/factorial(i) 
      }
      Y
```

Comment: Bienvenida bibitarifa a Stack Overflow en español, es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta para que ésta sea bien recibida por la comunidad.

Comment: Agrega por favor a tu pregunta lo que hubieras intentado hasta ahora. Saludos.

Comment: Hola @PatricioMoracho! Gracias por tu respuesta. Acabo de editar la publicación subiendo el código con lo que he intentado hasta ahora. Realmente me da un resultado, pero no sé con seguridad si está bien. Saludos.

Comment: ¿Qué representa `A`? ¿es un número o un vector?